# Oracle Procedure timing out

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

We were facing an issue of `ora-12609 tns receive timeout occurred` whenever we invoke any stored procedure. Upon checking the `sqlnet.ora` file we saw that `SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT` was set to `300`. The SP ran for 5 minutes then it threw the error. So, I changed the value to `3000` and for next 2 runs the SP was completed successfully. I would like to know for this aspect is there any other thing that needs to be checked from our side for the connection and timeout issue.
Do let me know if any more information is required from my side. TIA.

**Note:** The  SP taking more than 5 minutes is normal in our scenario as it is batch process to load data(kind of existing code can definitely look into the code and try to fine tune but that currently is secondary for us).

**Environment:** Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit